# Sybase Query : Alternative of LIST() in ASE

Tags: sql, subquery, sybase

Could you please help me to find out below query in Sybase.

I want a comma separated Row list. There is one LIST() aggregate function but I can't use that because I am using Adaptive Server Enterprise.

Is there any alternative query exist in Sybase to get LIST()  ?

For your reference:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1604/doc/html/jcu1290709667623.html

Thanks,
Samrat Sarkar

Comment: I want to get comma separated list from sub query.

Answer (score 3):

In ASE there are basically two options: (i) use a loop-based algorithm like a cursor (ii) use a little-known feature of the ASE UPDATE statement which can accumulate values over subsequent rows into a variable.

As for the latter, basically the idea is not updating any columns, but scanning through the rows like this:

```
update Sales
set @cnt = @cnt + 1,
    @sum = @sum + Amount
```

For full details, see my book www.sypron.nl/ttr.

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Comment: @RobV epic "hack", is this working fine for every ase version?

Comment: yes, this has been part of ASE as long as I can remember

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that with below technique,

I have created one #temp table and loop through cursor and inserted comma separated value in #temp table.

Now in main select query join with #temp table